# how to pass a private int to an objekt in another class in java

Tags: java, getter-setter

i try to use the 2 private values from class Test2 to a but i get an error saying that a is not initialized. Can someone help me? (I am new to Java)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Test{

   Test2 a = new Test2(a.getTestArray(), a.getNum1());
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Test2{
  private int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  private int num1 = 3;

  public void setTestArray(int[] testArray){
    this.testArray = testArray;
    }
  public void setNum1(int num1){
    this.num1 = num1;
    }
  public int[] getTestArray(){
    return this.testArray;
    }
  public int getNum1(){
    return num1;
    }
  public Test2(int[] testArray, int num1){
    this.testArray = testArray;
    this.num1 = num1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Test2 a = new Test(a.getTestArray(), a.getNum1());
```

You're trying to call a method on the thing you're initializing (`a`), before you've assigned a value to it.

I suspect you mean something like:

```
a anA = new a();
Test2 test2 = new Test(anA.getTestArray(), anA.getNum1());
```

You don't actually want to do this on a field in class `Test`, because then you'll get a `StackOverflowError`, because you are creating a `Test` every time you create a `Test`, which creates a `Test`, which creates a `Test` etc.

You probably mean to do it inside a method, something like:

```
public class Test extends Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      a anA = new a();
      Test2 test2 = new Test(anA.getTestArray(), anA.getNum1());
    }
}
```

Note that you need to declare that `Test` either `implements Test2` or `extends Test2` (depending upon whether `Test2` is an interface or a class, respectively).

Comment: Adding on to this, OP please use [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Classes should be CapitalCase, variables should be camelCase. It will help you a lot in the future to prevent you from getting mixed up.

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning (and you wouldn't have to call variables awkward names like `anA` - actually, `a` would be permissible as the variable name, but giving classes and variables the same name is a baaad idea)

Comment: Thank you very much and well i am a beginner in java but i will try to use java naming conventions. how to do i mark this as solved?

Comment: @simos There is a checkmark you click on by his answer, but I don't think you can accept until you get higher reputation (15 or something I believe?).

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges you need 15 rep to *upvote* answers. It would be bizarre if you couldn't accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ah, in hindsight that does make much more sense heh. There you have it OP

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can't invoke a method from an not initialized variable,

In this line

```
 Test2 a = new Test2(a.getTestArray(), a.getNum1());
```

the jvm trying this:

```
  Test2 a;
  int temp1[] = a.getTestArray(); // this fails because 'a' is not initialized
  int temp2 = a.getNum1());
  a = new Test2(temp1, temp2 );
```

i suggest you add a new static field in Test

```
private static int[] DEFAULT_TEST_ARRAY = {1, 2, 3, 4};
private static int[] DEFAULT_NUM = 3;
```

and in the Test2 remove default values

```
   private int[] testArray;
   private int num1;
```

As we create static attributes, we can use them without creating a new object, using the class as a reference instead of a variable.

```
Test2 a = new Test2(Test.DEFAULT_TEST_ARRAY,  Test.DEFAULT_NUM );
```

ps. you can move DEFAULT_TEST_ARRAY, DEFAULT_NUM  to Test2